# How to define array of numbers in google spreadsheets

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I need to create array of numbers between a and b for later use in ArrayFormula.
For example: hardcoded for a=2, b=5 it would be {2,3,4,5}

This seems very basic, but i failed to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using INDIRECT to define a range (like A2:A5) and then ROW to get the rows as numbers

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&a&":A"&b)))
```

I'm testing it by using SUMPRODUCT to total up the numbers {2,3,4,5} = 14 but you should be able to use it in a different formula. The values a and b are defined using named ranges.

Comment: What a smart and hacky way, I wouldnt see it on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The "A" isn't strictly necessary, but if you take it out and use a range like 2:5 it stops you putting the formula anywhere in those rows because you would get a circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

Can use the SEQUENCE function for this purpose:

```
=SEQUENCE(1, 5 - 2 + 1, 2)
```